# Node.js: declare node_modules globally, or locally on a as-needed basis?

Tags: node.js, dependencies, global, local

Should node_modules dependencies be declared globally at the start of the application code, or declared locally at the point they're required? I'm wondering if there's a best practice.

For example, I bootstrap my application using an `index.js` and require scripts when they're needed. My `security.js` module might, for example, need use of `node_hash`. Now, should I require that in `security.js` as

```
var node_hash = require('node_hash')
```

or globally require it in `index.js` so it's available to `security.js` (but also everything else)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Node, there's not really a concept of "require globally." When you require a module into another module, the required module is *only* available in the module you required it into. If you want to use that required module elsewhere, you will need to require it again (or somehow pass the returned object into your other modules).

Thus, the correct (only, really) answer is to require them where needed. Note that Node uses a [require cache](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html#modules_caching), so the required module is only really evaluated once, and the same object is returned for multiple requires of the same file.

[Edit] Assigning to a variable declared without `var` assigns it to the `global` scope (e.g. it can be accessed via `global` in Node). Very rarely do you want to do this; not only does it make it difficult to determine where a variable was declared, but it can also cause namespacing issues.

Comment: Well, I can have `node_hash = require('node_hash')` (note absence of 'var') and that will be applied globally to all required modules thereafter because I've written code that works like that. I want to know if assigning modules to a global variable was good/bad practice.

Comment: I see what you mean; updating my answer.